# How can I reset the brush settings for all paths in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, calligraphy

So three days ago I opened Adobe Illustrator for the first time in my life to prepare some embroidery patterns for my Christmas gifts. I never did on-screen calligraphy before, only on paper, so it took me some time to adjust to the screen and the file size, and I rescaled some of the letters and strokes a few times before deciding on the current brush settings. Right now, everything seems okay.

[image: calligraphy example before changes]

However, I have decided to make the brush rounder so that all the thin details don't get lost during the embroidery process. I selected all the paths, created a new brush and applied it to all of them. After that, some letters end up being almost twice as thick as the rest for some reason.

[image: after an attempt to change the brush settings]

Suprisingly enough, some of the problematic strokes were never even rescaled. I drew the D and the S from scratch long after deciding on the current brush, for example.
How can I reset the brush settings for all paths and apply the new brush to all of them for a consistent look?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This is hard to answer without access to the AI file, so this is only a guess. It looks like some of your strokes have variable size.  When you made your calligraphy brushes, did you enable the variable size option?  Try disabling that. Perhaps set the "Basic" stroke option to try to reset everything, then try to apply a new brush.  Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/InHRaPp) which might help you.

Comment: Also, maybe consider sharing the AI file, if you want us to examine it in detail.

Comment: Are you using a tablet or some other pressure sensitive device for input?

Comment: In any event, you can "remove brush stroke" then reapply it.

Comment: @Scott thank you so much! Remove brush stroke helped, and I now have everything pleasantly uniform.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the brush stroke from the paths.

Merely click the `Basic` item in the **Brush Panel** 
(Which *really* means "Basic path - no brush stroke".)

Then click the brush you *want* to use.

This should apply the new brush with the default settings for that brush.